# Copying Grass data from one location to another in Grass GIS

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

I have created several Grass locations with single mapsets while processing a series of satellite imageries at different stages of my analysis.

Now I need to copy some preprocessed rasters and vectors from the older locations to my current location and mapset. I am aware of using 'g.copy' which can be used in case of a single grass location and different mapsets. I know I can also export the rasters and vectors and import into my current location.

But found it wasting time as those data are already imported in Grass and all these Grass Locations are in same 'region' settings and with same projections.

Any hack for adding those rasters and vectors in my current Location and mapset?

USing Grass GIS 7.4 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an overview as it depends on the projection(s):

When the **projection is the same** across the different locations, then

- you either can simply copy/move the respective mapset in location A to location B,
- or, at map level, you can use [r.pack](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.pack.html)/[v.pack](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.pack.html) to package maps and unpack them in the target mapset with [r.unpack](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.unpack.html)/[v.unpack](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.unpack.html) in a lossless way.

When **projections differ** across the different locations, then

- you need to **export** the maps ([r.out.gdal](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.out.gdal.html)/[v.out.ogr](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.out.ogr.html), e.g. to GeoTIFF/GeoPackage) and **import** in the target mapset with [r.import](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.import.html)/[v.import](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.import.html).

Answer (score 0):

If projection is different you might be better off using r.proj or v.proj to bring a map into your current location and mapset from another.